# Why the use of open bracket and close bracket to declare a variable in Java

Tags: java

Can someone please explain the use of the following code in Java

```
private TableColumn<Books, Integer> colId;
```

I want to know the reason of using `<?,?>` to declare a variable in Java.

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - Lesson: Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are 'Generics'. Specifically, the things inside the brackets are called 'Type Parameters'. It allows different types to be chosen when you create the object or 'variable' as you call it.

So you could have a list of numbers with: `new ArrayList<Integer>()`

or a list of strings with: `new ArrayList<String>()`

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm

In your example, it's creating a column to keep track of ids for books. The ids will be ints and the object they are identifying is books. But, you may want another TableColumn (which behaves the same as the Book Id column) but for tracking the titles of the books: `TableColumn<Books, String> colTitle`

Comment: They aren't generic variables, they are *type parameters*.

Comment: Good point. I'll update my wording.